# IP6Tables: How to enable external access to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, iptables, remote, ip6tables

How to enable external access to MySQL with rules on ip6tables?

I have tried to the rules below, where after inserted I get access, but when server restart the access remains blocked.

```
:INPUT DROP [2:144]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s [static ipv6 here]/128 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s [static ipv6 here]/128 -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
```

IPTables is enabled too.

Thanks!

Comment: You've read some really bad Internet tutorials. Here you'll find a [working firewall configuration](http://serverfault.com/a/410327/126632).

Answer (score 0):

Michael, I really appreciate your suggestion. My new table looks like this:

```
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [46:5592]
-A INPUT -m rt --rt-type 0 --rt-segsleft 0 -j DROP 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s [static ipv6 here]/128 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable 
-A FORWARD -m rt --rt-type 0 --rt-segsleft 0 -j DROP 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable 
-A OUTPUT -m rt --rt-type 0 --rt-segsleft 0 -j DROP 
COMMIT
```

Works fine now. Thank you!